# Hapi Conversion from HL7 2.31 to HL7 2.5

Tags: hl7, hapi

Hapi includes a parser function that can parse specific HL7 version to alternate versions:

```
HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();
        CanonicalModelClassFactory mcf = new CanonicalModelClassFactory("2.5");
        context.setModelClassFactory(mcf);
        PipeParser parser = context.getPipeParser();
        parser.getParserConfiguration().setIdGenerator(new InMemoryIDGenerator());

        context.getParserConfiguration().setValidating(false);

        ADT_AXX axx = null;

        try {
            axx = (ADT_AXX) parser.parse(message.toString());
        }
        catch (HL7Exception e) {
            log.warn("Exception parsing to AXX");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In version 2.31 Attending doctors are messaged in PV1.7-9.  In 2.5 there is a ROL segment which holds this information.  My issue is that the Hapi parser does not seem to parse PV1.7.9 into ROL.  I don't think this is the correct behaviour?  Any support guidance appreciated?

Comment: What's the message you parse and what's the error message you receive? I don't know too much about `hapi`, but I would try to find the answer in the source code responsible for the message mapping and I'd expect there to be some configurable maps. As the longer there is the `hl7` protocol the more dynamic and message-profile-driven it becomes. BTW: I don't think that at this low-level the library should pretend it sees something else then what there really is. It's usually business of some upper abstraction layers

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however I think that the answer was more straight forward than I had assumed.

Answer (score 1):

In case others stumble across this, the most straight forward answer is that 2.5 also has a PV1.7 segment so the most sensible thing is for the parser to map the PV1.7 data from version 2.31 to the same segment in version 2.5 rather than (as I had assumed) mapping to ROL segments... And this is exactly what it does.